# Achartengine zoom button

Tags: android, achartengine

When I press with finger the "+" button (shown in picture) and then call the method MyGraphicalView.repaint() the zoom  it resets. Is there a way that when I click on the "+" and after invoking MyGraphicalView.repaint() the zoom it increases?

[image]

I tried so:

```
float zoom ;
MyGraphicalView.addZoomListener(new ZoomListener()
{
  @Override
  public void zoomApplied(ZoomEvent zoomEvent)
  {
   zoom = zoomEvent.getZoomRate();
  }
  @Override
  public void zoomReset() {}
},true, true);


 runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
 {
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
    MyGraphicalView.setZoomRate(zoom);
    MyGraphicalView.repaint();
   }
  });
```

that is, if I press the "+" button will not have effect. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach a [ZoomEvent](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/index.html) listener in your graphical view. Whenever the zoom is used , you will call the `getZoomRate()` method and you will keep the returning value of method in a float.

Then, whenever you need to call the `repaint` method, you will call the method `setZoomRate(float zoom)` to your graphical view.